# Replacing Values in SAS dataset

Tags: sas

I want a code to replace the numerics into character in the column.

**For example :0-"No  1-"Yes".**

I tried using if/else but its not working!!!

```
Data Assign2.Grocery_coup_two;                                                                                                          
Set Assign2.Grocery_coupons;                                                                                                            
If Heath_food_Store = 0                                                                                                                 
then Health_food_Store = "No";                                                                                                          
Else Health_food_Store = "Yes";                                                                                                         
Run;    





Health_Food_Store
0
0
0
0
1
0
1
0
0
0
1
0
1
0
0
1
```

Comment: How is it not working ?  Are you getting log messages ? Are you getting results that don't meet your expectations ? Please tell what kind of variable `Health_Food_Store` is in data set `Assign2.Grocery_coupons`.  Do you know about SAS custom formats ? A custom format can change 0/not 0 to No/Yes for presentation purposes.

Comment: Do you know the difference between a numeric and character variable? Which type is your variable?  It cannot be both at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is using SAS format. Just like how you might format numeric variables as dates (e.g. DATE9. is popular) you can create your own formats.

This is extremely useful if you don't want to repeat your if...then statements through out your codes.

In your case a solution like below may be useful.

```
Proc format;
value $YN
1 = 'Yes'
0 = 'No'
;
run;

Data Assign2.Grocery_coup_two;  
Set Assign2.Grocery_coupons;
format Health_food_Store $YN.;
run;
```

The `proc format` statement creates the new format `$YN` which is applied to  `Health_food_Store` with the `set`condition.

Comment: Thanks sir!! This is the one i was looking for

Answer (score 5):

Your solution is not working because you're trying to convert a numeric variable into a string variable. One way to fix this is to rename your numeric variable into _old, and then run the if-else statement:

```
Data Assign2.Grocery_coup_two;                                                                                                          
    Set Assign2.Grocery_coupons (rename = (Health_food_Store = Health_food_Store_old));                                                                                                            
    If Heath_food_Store_old = 0                                                                                                                 
    then Health_food_Store = "No";                                                                                                          
    Else Health_food_Store = "Yes";                                                                                                         
    DROP Health_food_Store_old;
Run;
```